# Why is window.onload function not working for my other vue page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have 2 pages or "views" with identical JS. In there I have a window.onload function in which I do some stuff:

```
console.log("loading")

window.onload = function() {
console.log("loaded")
// do stuff
}
```

`window.onload` is just skipped and not executed at all here, never makes it to `console.log("loaded")`.

`window.onload` works fine on `Index.vue` which is the main or first page that loads, but not when you navigate to `About.vue`. I'm at a loss and can't find anything that can help me. All I can think of is that maybe this is some issue with the router and how vue.js loads stuff. What's wrong?

Comment: there can be only one `window.onload` in a page at a time ... the fact that you're using vue-router suggests perhaps an SPA? so when About.vue is loaded, it's not a page laod - note: try refreshing the page when you're in About.vue - see what happens

Comment: This is most likely XY problem, and you're misusing onload. It's rarely ever needed in Vue app. Consider addressing your case in whole instead of potentially wrong solution

Comment: I use `window.onload` because `document.getElement`/`document.querySelector` return null due to trying to find the elements before they're loaded in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will not execute after you navigate as the DOM already loaded, you can execute your code without `window.load` there.

If you want to ensure that the component itself is mounted to the DOM, you can use `mounted` Vue lifecycle.

Comment: Using `mounted()` works, but this breaks my opening page animation which I do by removing/adding classes to specific divs with predefined animation delays and durations. It seems to ignore any duration I've given it and does everything instantaneously.